Did any early church writers reject the deity of Christ as blasphemous?
This question is not asking about the specific Christology of any given early church writer. All I want to know is if any early church writer ever made a claim that calling Christ God is blasphemous.
I’m aware any given writer would likely be outside orthodoxy, but that is not relevant to me. I just want to know if there was any such writer.

Perhaps the following will address your question.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82708/is-there-any-historical-evidence-of-early-church-christians-denying-the-divinity

@Mr.Bond You might be right. That said I’m going to leave my question up because I’m not satisfied by the answers given there. The top answer basically just says “there wasn’t any mention of Christ’s divinity till the 3rd century”. That’s false, and it’s an argument from silence rather than a demonstration of church fathers who claimed Christ was not divine AGAINST believers in Christ’s divinity.

Considering a broader scope for the subjects, not limited to the Roman Orthodox Christianity, it is difficult to find explicit condemnation of the high Christology which makes Jesus co-equal with God the father. That is because all those heresies also believed him to be divine/ God. Ebionites believed him to be an angel incarnate in Jesus. The Gnostics believed he was too divine to be man and suffer death as a mortal. These two are the best candidates who must have severely condemned the mainstream Christology or trinity as blasphemous. If the Gnostics believed YHWH as an evil lesser god, then how much they would've hated if Christians equated Jesus with him!
If you want to trace a greater degree of hatred to the mainstream Christian view then you should go down a few centuries until the Nasara Gnostics evolved into Islam till 7-8th century, and we see the commands of murdering and even crucifying the worshippers of Christ (Q 9:29-30, 5:33).

If you could provide any citations of writers within these groups calling believers in Christ’s divinity blasphemers, that would probably help me accept this answer. I was already aware of these groups existence.

Blasphemy and strong condemnation was the practice of the authoritative mainstream church against all who disagreed with them. So It's hard to find any quotes like that

are you saying the mainstream early church blasphemed against all who disagreeed with them? I’m confused by your comment.

Yes, basically that's how a heresy is condemned, I think Arius' doctrine must have been characterised as blasphemous, as it is in present time.

Understood. So is it then your claim that these same mainstream Christians suppressed the writings of these groups such that we no longer have them?

Other doctrines and disagreements were not allowed, they were killed and of course their writings would not survive much. Even though we may not have explicit quote, we can assume that others also condemned the mainstream doctrine. Just like today the minority "heresies" can openly condemn, they must have also condemned them in ancient times; nothing changes. To know history, u can just see the present.  Augustin has been called the father of inquisition.

what’s your evidence that murder occurred over these doctrines? I’m aware of the suppression of the texts themselves but not anything like killing heretics.

I have heard from Arminian articles that Augustin was called the Father of inquisition. It will be a good question to make here. I personally don't need explicit written records to believe the antisemitism and anti Christian genocide theoughiut history especially early centuries. When they even killed many Xians during reformation timed and in USA, u shouldn't doubt the works of ancient people.
